# Can android locator api locate something inside a building

Tags: android

I know android api can locate something using gps, but since gps doesn't work inside a building I'm wondering can android api locate something inside a building?

Answer (score 0):

The act of being in a building doesn't prevent GPS from working, it is the signal of the GPS that is the deciding factor.  If you can get a signal with the GPS in a building, you can get your location.

Comment: Whether the granularity of the location would be useful in the context of locating yourself inside a building is another question, though.

Comment: Excellent point.  Perhaps you can get a good estimation of which floor you are on in a skyscraper though...

Answer (score 0):

There is something called A-GPS or Network GPS which can give you location by using different technique.

Please read this for more detail. 
http://www.backcountrynavigator.com/content/android-gps

Answer (score 0):

There are no APIs within Android to give you that degree of in-building accuracy. You are welcome to invent something of your own, perhaps using the signal strength from a series of access points and creating your own map of strength values to coordinates.